# Dotted decimal to binary in C

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have an `in_addr` struct with an IP address that I'm trying to convert from dotted decimal to a binary value.  What I really need to do, but can't make work, is something like

```
destn = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(addr));
```

where `addr` is the `in_addr_t` variable.  I know that violates the syntax, but when I follow the syntax more carefully, I get an error:

```
storage size of ‘addr’ isn’t known.
```

Comment: Do you mean a binary value in the sense of the text "11000000101010000000000000000001" or in the sense of a 32 bit unsigned integer?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified -- in the sense of a 32 bit unsigned int.

Comment: what is `dotted decimal`? give example, edit your question to readable form, don't input randomized information, it may get it closed

Comment: @chouaib [Dotted decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation) is the standard form of representing an IP address. Just because you don't know something doesn't mean its "randomized information". Do your research before telling the OP to modify his question.

Comment: @s_frank "Dotted decimal" is just one way of textually representing an IPv4 address. A 32-bit hex value is another, and a string of ones and zeros is another. If you have an `in_addr` struct, you've already got the value in "binary" form in memory. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish next with this value? Print it out? I think you need to show more of your code. This question can't be answered as it is now.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Dude the question as it was before editing was looking randomized (without including Dotted int!) otherwise I guess it's a NO-SENSE act from you to edit it, right? I may not know the terminology but I can give a serious try once it's explained, so I do believe it's the OP JOB to explain his points not me to do extra searches just to understand his question!!

Comment: @chouaib Yes, the formatting was poor, probably because the OP was unfamiliar with markdown syntax. I fixed it. It's not a big deal. But my statement about "dotted decimal" still applies. It is an [**industry-standard term**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation), on a question about network programming. I'm sorry you were unaware of it. Do you expect the OP to explain to you what an IP address is, too, because you don't want to "do extra searches"?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: You don't need to be sorry for me , I'm here to learn as much as to help, and yes I do expect the OP to say what is IP address if I don't know it, giving an example "172.020.009.200" doesn't hurt after all

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks for fixing my post -- I'll definitely bone up on markdown syntax!  I'm going to use the binary value in a bitwise LPM procedure with a mask.  It's a klugey approach but I like the clanging sound it makes :)

Answer (score 2):

If you already have an IPv4 address in a `struct in_addr` variable, then there is nothing you need to do:

```
/* Internet address. */
struct in_addr {
    uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
};
```

See [`ip(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html). Simply access the `s_addr` field, and you have your IPv4 address in a simple 32-bit integer.

Example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct in_addr addr = {};
    const char *ip_str;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s ip-addr\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    ip_str = argv[1];

    if (!inet_aton(ip_str, &addr)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid IP address: %s\n", ip_str);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Address: 0x%08"PRIX32"\n", addr.s_addr);
    // Just access the s_addr field --------^

    return 0;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror in.c 
$ ./a.out 192.168.7.4
Address: 0x0407A8C0
           ^ ^ ^ ^
           | | | \---- 192
           | | \------ 168
           | \-------- 7
           \---------- 4
```

Answer (score 1):

For future compatibility, you should handle both IP 4 and 6. Otherwise, you might have mentioned inet_ntoa instead of inet_ntop. (My phone uses IP 6, so I need to allow for it if I do IP programming on my phone.) So, how? Here's how I'd start:

```
char *address_string;
```

(Fill in the value of `address_string`.)

```
struct in_addr addr4;
int success4 = inet_pton(AF_INET, address_string, addr4);
struct in6_addr addr6;
int success6 = inet_pton(AF_INET6, address_string, addr6);
```

You'll want to add error handling, of course.

If you're trying to get a text representation of a binary IP number instead, this should do the job:

```
struct in_addr addr4;
struct in6_addr addr6;
bool address_is_ip6;
```

(Fill in the value of the IP 4 or 6 address, and note which one you're using.)

```
socklen_t ip6_maximum_length = 40;
char address_string[ip6_maximum_length];
char *result = inet_ntop(address_is_ip6 ? AF_INET6 : AF_INET, address_is_ip6 ? &addr6 : &addr4, address_string, ip6_maximum_length);
```

Again, you'll need error handling.

Comment: While this is good general advice, it doesn't answer the OP's question (probably because we don't know what he *actually needs*). He indicates he already has a `in_addr` struct with the IP address, so parsing a string doesn't seem to be appropriate here.

Comment: The original question was a bit unclear, mentioning on the one hand that the starting point was an `in_addr` structure, and that the intention was "to convert from dotted decimal to a binary value." On the basis of the binary value "in the sense of a 32 bit unsigned int" reply to my clarification question, I assumed that the intention was to convert from text to `in_addr` (or `in6_addr`) structure, and offered code for that. **Why the down vote?** Anyway, now I've provided code to convert both ways.